# Receive JSON from body and iterate over it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a PUT method (or POST, whichever works) which takes in JSON (`content-type:application/json`) as the body and then iterates over it, writing the (key, value) contents to the console. I am unsure how to take the JSON as an input, as using `[FromBody] string data` returns the following error: `"The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."`.

So to fix this I am using the `dynamic` type. However, I am then unable to iterate over the key-value pairs of this datatype. The input JSON will be random every time so I can't create a class for it.

PUT method:

```cs
[HttpPut("{something}")]
public ActionResult update(string something, [FromBody] dynamic data)
{

}
```

Sample JSON:

```
{"id":"123","name":"sample name"}
```

What I've tried:

The following line: `var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);`

outputs an error:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best
> overloaded method match for
> 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>>(string)'
> has some invalid arguments

Expected output to the console after successful iteration over the JSON data:

```
id: 123
name: some name
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Posting dictionary to web api in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39214338/posting-dictionary-to-web-api-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 1):

Just as soon as I post the question - I find the answer

```
[HttpPut("{something}")]
public ActionResult update(string something, [FromBody] Dictionary<string, string> data)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> value in data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);

    }
}
```

I can take a dictionary as an input - which presumably allows C# to deserialize the JSON for me.