# How to process forms in ASP.NET Core with unknown fields

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create an Http `post` method that will be able to process html forms of different inputs.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string content)
{
    // process content here.
    return View("Success");
}
```

My method should be able to support this form

```
<form action="url" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="firstName">
    <input type="text" name="lastName">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

as well as this form

```
<form action="url" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="surname">
    <input type="text" name="age">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How can I modify my method so that the content will be populated for both of these cases?

Comment: I think you should be able to [use `FromBody` on a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39214338/posting-dictionary-to-web-api-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I modify my method so that the content will be populated for
> both of these cases?

Well, based on your scenario and requirement,we have two option other than `[FormBody]` pattern,to deal with completely dynamic value, we can use `IFormCollection` and a `Dictionary`.
Our goal is to handle any dynamic data which we will finally add into our `Dictionary` using its `Key` and `Value`.

**Completely Dynamic Form Request Example:**

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(IFormCollection dynamicData)
    {
                 
        var dynamicFormDataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (var item in dynamicData)
        {

            dynamicFormDataDictionary.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            dynamicFormDataDictionary.Remove("__RequestVerificationToken");
        }
       
        return View("DynamicOutput", dynamicFormDataDictionary);
    }
```

[image]
[image]

**Note:** We cannot use `FormCollection` because it will encounter runtime exception as it has `Interface` of `IFormCollection` type. .

**Bind Dynamic Data And Display in View:**

Controller:

```cs
public IActionResult DynamicOutput()
        {
         
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```cs
@model Dictionary<string, object>
<h4>Dynamic Data</h4>
<table class="table">
    @foreach (var key in Model.Keys)
    {
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <th>
                    @key
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Model[key]
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    }
</table>
```

Output:

[image]

**Alternative Way:**

We have another way, which is using `Request.Form` but here we need to define our data fields. In following way we can get the data:

```cs
            var input1 = Request.Form["firstName"].GetValue();
            var input2 = Request.Form["name"].GetValue();
```

**Note:** Point to remember, in this way, let's say, you have two `request from` we would define all the property together and allow `null-value`. Therefore, we would get our desired value from one `request form` while other we would remain empty.

Answer (score 2):

To process forms with unknown fields, you can use the `FormCollection` type as a parameter in the `Create` method. The `FormCollection` type represents a collection of keys and values that are sent as the HTTP request body when the form is submitted. You can use this type to capture all the form data, regardless of the number or names of the fields.

To access the form data, you can use the `formData` object. For example, you can access a field with the name "firstName" using the following syntax: `formData["firstName"]`.

`PdfController.cs`:

```cs
public class PdfController: Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(IFormCollection formData)
    {
        // process form data here
        var surName= formData["surname"].ToString();
        
        return View("Create", (FormCollection)formData);
    }
}
```

Form:

```html
<form action="/pdf/create" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="surname">
    <input type="text" name="age">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

`Create.cshtml`:

```html
@model FormCollection
<h1>Form Data</h1>

<table>
    @foreach (var key in Model.Keys)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@key</td>
            <td>@Model[key]</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

View:
[image: FormData object view]

Comment: `FormCollection` will throw runtime exception if you don't explicitly use `ModelBinder class`. Instead, to keep the hassle aside, we can use `IFormCollection interface`.